# Why can't I answer a protected question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

As you can see, I have 101 rep here. Also, I can't answer [protected questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/sing-happy-birthday-to-your-favourite-programming-language?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) even though they say I only need 10 rep:

[image: a screenshot of it denying my answer]

Answer (score 3):

[Protection ignores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question) the account [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati). You are being treated as brand new because you *are* new to this site.

Comment: Interesting... I thought the association bonus was because I was already trusted. But now it doesn't mean I'm trusted? I'm confused about this mechanic

Comment: Well, you are trusted for *most* things. I've added a link to a meta.stackexchange question that might be worth reading.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go join that conversation!

Answer (score 2):

You need 10 rep *without* counting the association bonus.

Comment: perhaps that should be in the message... I didn't know an association bonus could be discounted